# Find element and change its content in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I Want to change default content of my header div:

```
<div>
  <div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1><span>{{messages['default_title']}}</span></h1>
      </div>
  <div>
  <!-- other elements-->
<div>
```

In my controller, i wrote this:

```
var titleElement = angular.element('div.page-header');
titleElement.html('<h1><span>Hello</span></h1>');
```

The content of div changes successfully:

```
<div class="page-header"><h1><span>Hello</span></h1></div>
```

But i get this error, and page can't be loaded successfully:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
    at g (https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular.min.js:47:278)
    at g (https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular.min.js:47:273)
    at g (https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular.min.js:47:273)
    at g (https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular.min.js:47:273)
    at g (https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular.min.js:47:273)
    at https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular.min.js:46:377
    at link (https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular-route.js:915:7)
    at J (https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular.min.js:54:373)
    at g (https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular.min.js:47:256)
    at https://localhost/test/js/angular/angular.min.js:46:377 <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to mix AngularJS and jQuery syntax...

Comment: Change the data model, not the DOM. Also no dom code should be present in controller

Comment: @charlietfl, The message variable should not be manipulated. and in some cases the title is a static text.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense...why are you manipulating DOM then? And why can't the message be manipulated ( or some other variable). What you are doing is contrary to the way angular should be used

Comment: First i fetch some initial info. Based on them, I want to load some html pages dynamically in my main-page. Each inner page has <div class="page-header"> ... </div> element which i want to change them based on initial info.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manipulating the page-header.

Try to update the variable in your controller

```
$scope.messages['default_title'] = "Hello";
```

Comment: I missed something in the question. my page-header divs can also have static text: <span>Goodby</span>

Comment: And also i can't change the message variable. (it should not be manipulated)

Answer (score 1):

`angular.element` accepts a string of HTML or a JS element, not a selector

```
var titleElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('.page-header'));
titleElement.html('<h1><span>Hello</span></h1>');
```

Comment: Do you have an element with that class ?

Comment: Yes, <div class="page-header"> .... </div>. it changes content of the div, but gets error.